# Converting from CSV chr input to date in R returning NA

Tags: r

I know there are many similar questions posted, but I couldn't get any of them to fix my issue.
I imported data from a csv using read.csv
The first column is a date column (defined as YYY-MM-DD in google sheets).

In R the str(data.df) yields

```
$ Date                    : chr  "2021-02-21" "2021-02-22" "2021-02-23" "2021-02-24"
```

I have tried the following (in all sort of variations)

```
as.Date(stripe.df$Date[1], format="%y/%m/%d")
strptime(stripe.df$Date[1],format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

Anyone have any idea what I can do to convert this to date so I could use it in plots and trees etc?

Thanks,

Comment: Use could use `lubridate::ymd(stripe.df$Date[1])` or replace your format by `format="%Y-%m-%d"`.

Comment: You need the format you give `as.Date` to match the format of your string. Your vector has hyphens but you told the function to look for slashes. It's essentially a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't have to subset the vector, unless you only want to transform only the first element. Second, you don't have to specify the format because YYYY-MM-DD is the standard the `as.Date` expect. In your specific case you just need:

```r
char <- c("2021-02-21" ,"2021-02-22", "2021-02-23", "2021-02-24")
str(char)
#>  chr [1:4] "2021-02-21" "2021-02-22" "2021-02-23" "2021-02-24"
date <- as.Date(char)
str(date)
#>  Date[1:4], format: "2021-02-21" "2021-02-22" "2021-02-23" "2021-02-24"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You need to specify the format when the input is not standard:

```r
char <- c("02/21/20210" ,"02/22/2021", "02/23/20210", "02/24/2021")
str(char)
#>  chr [1:4] "02/21/20210" "02/22/2021" "02/23/20210" "02/24/2021"
date <- as.Date(char, format="%m/%d/%Y")
str(date)
#>  Date[1:4], format: "2021-02-21" "2021-02-22" "2021-02-23" "2021-02-24"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: AMAZING!!! thank you so much! that solved it! I can't believe it was SO simple.